# Is it better to use the user interface thread or the game update thread for sending messages to the main activity, i.e. admob View messages?

Tags: android, multithreading, admob

Is it better to use the user interface thread or the game update thread for sending view.visible and view.gone messages to the main activity to show and hide an admob message banner? For example:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
  switch(action){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      if(loginRectF[RESUME_BUTTON].contains(touchF_x,touchF_y)){
        handlerActivity.sendEmptyMessage(View.GONE);
```

vs

```
public void update() {//update thread in game   
   if(resumeflag){
        handlerActivity.sendEmptyMessage(View.GONE);
```

I've found both methods work reasonably well, but I expect good programming practice would recommend one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this depends on your logic. If you want to show the message when something happens on your background thread, it is OK to notify the UI thread from this point.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases above you ARE using the UI Thread. When you call `Handler.sendEmptyMessage` you are queuing a (View.GONE) message for the UI thread.